# How can I access certain table rows in a for loop?

Tags: jquery, django

I wan't to highlight only the contacts of a company they're related to in my table body. At the moment I'm only able to highlight all of the contacts regardless of which company's contacts they are. I don't think I can use find() method since the contact row is different from he company row.

## tbody

```
{% for company in company_list %}
    <tr id="company-row">
        <th id="company-name" scope="row">{{ company.name }}</th>
        <td>{{ company.order_count }}</td>
        <td id="order-sum">{{ company.order_sum|floatformat:2 }}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="select{{company.pk}}" id=""></td>
    </tr>
    {% for contact in company.contacts.all %}
         <tr id="contact-row">
             <td>{{ contact.first_name }} {{ contact.last_name }}</td>
             <td id="contact-orders">Orders: {{ contact.order_count }}</td>
             <th>&nbsp;</th>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

## script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#company-row").hover(function() {
        sum = $(this).find("#order-sum").html() // get value of total sales

        if (sum > 50000) {
            $(this).addClass("company-row-over") // green

            $("#contact-row").each(function() {
                orders = $(this).find("#contact-orders").html() // get orders from each contact
                orders = orders.split(':')
                orders = orders[1]
                orders = parseInt(orders)

                if (orders > 3) {
                    $(this).addClass("contacts") // yellow
                }
            })
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("company-row-under") // orange
        }
    },

    // clear highlighting on mouse out
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass()
        $("#contact-row").removeClass()
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you please share the requirements to become the contact row highlighted?

Comment: A contact of the company must have over 3 orders from of that specific company and the company must have more than 50000 in sales which is stored in the sum variable. Both the orders and sum variables work fine and are correct, I checked it by logging them to the console.

Comment: The selectors use the same id for all contact rows. If the idea is to select only for one company, they must have a id that relates to the company (ex: the company Key)

Comment: nvm, I solved it...